# How can you specify which requirejs modules should load in a html file

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I can't find an answer to this anywhere. Does this need to be done or does the optimiser do this somehow?

If a minified requirejs file became very large would it be suitable to break my_main.js down and possibly use my_main1 and my_main2?

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="my_main.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a vague question. Are you certain you can't find your answer in the extensive documentation? - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify which modules you want via your "require" and "define" calls...

Your index.html will have a tag such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="my_main.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Inside "my_main.js" you'd do something like:

```
require(["module1", "module2"], function(module1, module2) {
});
```

which would load in module1 and module2.

When you decide to optimise your code, the optimiser will look through all the modules you load and all their dependencies and put them in a single minified file.  You'll only need to load that minified file in your index.html in an optimized build.

Comment: Is it common for a minified file of requirejs to get too large for effectively loading with every html file?

Comment: well I guess the browser will cache it for future page requests so that should take care of it...  How large has it gotten?